# How do I see entirely of the contents inside a an object with thousands of keys and values through chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If you paste an object with a thousand key/value pairs inside, and console log that object, Chrome Dev Tools will should you the first few key/value paris, and then `...` and then the rest of the key/value pairs. How do I see ALL of the key value pairs instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default object formatter will show you the first few properties, and then an ellipsis to indicate that other properties exist. You need to expand the object in the Console to view all the key values. Click the arrow on the left-side.

### Example:

[image: Expanding Large Object]

Comment: i clicked it but it doesn't show the first few key/values anymore, it skips down to show lower values

Comment: sorry, you're right it does show everything, I just couldn't see the first few properties, because the dev tools puts it in alphabetical order. do you know if I can disable this alphabetical ordering?

Comment: @akantoword I think this is built into the default object formatter in DevTools. You can write your own [Custom Object Formatter](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/02/19/custom-chrome-devtools-object-formatters.html) if it's a common issue you want to solve. However, if you just want a quick thing, write a `for` loop to output the contents in the order in which the the properties exist in the object.